# ZF2 Share partial view (menu) betwen controllers of same module

Tags: view, controller, zend-framework2

In ZF2 I have a module with more controllers, that shares let say the menu (for navigating betwen controllers).
To share this menu between the controllers I have to put this in every controller view:

```
<div class="span2">
<?php echo $this->partial('leftmenu'); ?>
</div>

<div class="span10">
THIS IS THE CONTROLLER VIEW
</div>
```

So I am repeating the `<?php echo $this->partial('leftmenu'); ?>` code everywhere. Is there a way for doing this just once and make it appear in all views of the controllers?

Comment: If it's meant to display regardless of controller action, put it in the layout instead ?

Comment: I cannot put in the layout because the layout is shared between all modules and modules have different controllers. Should I define a layout for this module apart?

Comment: if it's common to only one module, yes, a module specific layout would be the way to go

Comment: yes it is common to only one module. I can do a module specific layout but I need to share (for not repeating code) pieces of the main layout.... I will investigate more

Comment: I'd either go with an alternate layout for this Module or for a ViewHelper which displays the Menu only when a given ModuleName is matched by the route.

Comment: I just wonder if I can define a layout for the single module, but inside the main layout (let's call a sublayout)?

Answer (score 1):

One way wold be to inject a ViewModel into your layout and have it rendered in there.

Module.php

```
/**
 * On bootstrap event
 * 
 * @param \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e
 */
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    // .. 

    $viewModel = $e->getViewModel();
    $menu = new ViewModel();
    $menu ->setTemplate('module/menu/something');
    $viewModel->addChild($menu, 'menu');
}
```

You will just need to render the menu inside the layout then..

layout.phtml

```
<?php if(isset($menu)) echo $menu ?>
```

You can alternatively attach onto different events if you want different effects, such as only injecting the module if you're in a certain module, or into any controller which extends the abstract controller:

```
// Bootstrap ///

$e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager()
        ->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController', 'dispatch', function($e) {
    $controller = $e->getTarget();
    $controllerClass = get_class($controller);
    $moduleNamespace = substr($controllerClass, 0, strpos($controllerClass, '\\'));

    // logic to decide what you want

    $viewModel = $e->getViewModel();
    $menu = new ViewModel();
    $menu ->setTemplate('module/menu/something');
    $viewModel->addChild($menu, 'menu');
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to change partials depending on some conditions ex.

- side nav in layout
- side nav in view
  ...

You can set global in Module and if necesary change it from controller.

Module

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);

    $eventManager->attach('dispatch', array($this, 'loadViewVars'), 100);
    // 100-gives access for controller to overwrite this var
    // 1-prevents overwriting
}

public function loadViewVars(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $e->getViewModel()->setVariables(
        array('sideNavigation'=>'partial/sidenavigation_1.phtml',)
    );
}
```

Controller

```
//you can change in some controller by
$this->layout()->sideNavigation='partial/sidenavigation_2.phtml';
```

View

```
<?php echo $this->partial($this->layout()->sideNavigation); ?>
```